# As G Suite Admin, can I monitor in any way which Google API's (Gmail, etc) have been accessed for a list of user accounts

Tags: api, google-api, google-calendar-api, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

According to the docs, Google Apps domain administrators can grant service accounts domain-wide authority to access user data on behalf of users in the domain. My understating is this gives service account authority to access data for all users inside the domain.

Is there a way for the G Suite Admin to monitor or check which user accounts (and consequently which Google API's [Gmail API, Calendar API, Contacts API]):

a. have been accessed or not?

b. By whom have they been accessed?

c. When were they accessed?

d. How long were they accessed?

I ask this because I have extensively searched this information and found nothing. As a G Suite Admin, in the Reports section, the reports such as App Activity, Admin Audit Log, Account Activity, User Accounts Audit Log, etc have not provided me answers to the above 4 questions. Also, under API's and Services -> Dashboard, I can't view which API's were accessed, by whom, when were they accessed, etc? The Dashboard shows nothing? What is the dashboard supposed to show?

My requirement is to view and monitor details regarding access to user accounts.

Consider the following scenario:

There are 100 user accounts for a company (say, xyz.com) created under a service account and the G Suite Admin of xyz.com has provided API access (Gmail API, Calendar API and Contacts API through a JSON file) to a private website (for example, pqr.com). Even though pqr.com has domain authority access to all 100 users of xyz.com, pqr.com has only accessed 40 out of the 100 users of xyz.com.

Question: Is there a way where the G Suite Admin of xyz.com may know the following:

a. Which 40 user accounts (out of the 100 accounts of xyz.com) were accessed?

b. When were these 40 accounts accessed? (Day and Time, etc)

c. How long were they accessed for?

d. Also, consider if pqr.com agreed to access only 40 accounts of xyz.com but actually accessed, say 80 accounts, then G Suite Admin should of xyz.com should be able to track that. Is this possible?

Is there any alternative way to solve this problem?

Note: I have already searched for the solution where I wanted to know if API access (for e.g. Gmail, Contacts and Calendar API) could be provided through a JSON file by a G Suite Admin only for a list of users (not all users) for a service account (Created within a project) and research and responses on StackOverflow told me its not possible so I wanted to know if a monitoring mechanism is possible for domain-wide access?

Comment: You can only monitor API quotas through the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console), you can check there the usage and quota. Yes unfortunately, there's no available API to list the users analytics through a JSON response. You can probably also check the Administration privilege definitions for the user from this [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251?hl=en#API).

Comment: Hi Jess. Thank you for your response but I could not view anything in Google Cloud Platform Console related to my problem. Again, this is the problem I'm facing and would like your feedback on it if possible: Is there a way for the G Suite Admin to monitor or check which user accounts (and consequently which Google API's [Gmail API, Calendar API, Contacts API]):
a. have been accessed or not?
b. By whom have they been accessed?
c. When were they accessed?
d. How long were they accessed?

Answer (score 0):

You have that information in the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-tokens).

You have the scopes requested but it will not tell you exactly which API endpoints have been used. Also note that the tokens are valid for 1 hour so you can assume they were used at least for 1 hour after an "authorize" event.